# How to Map and reduce an array of Strings to a single object with multiple values

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, reduce

I have a document that looks like such:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("6222ca4252925ad4c3faec08"),
  value: ["test1","test2"]
}
```

I would like to get:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("6222ca4252925ad4c3faec08"),
 “value”:
    {  
      “value1”: "test1",
      “value2”: "test2"
     }
}
```

I have tried to use reduce but I get each value in one object but am very close.  Please let me know what I am doing wrong:

Code:

```
{
  "$project": {
    "value": {
      $reduce: {
        input: "$value",
        initialValue: [],
        in: {$concatArrays: [
          "$$value", 
          [{"name": "$$this"}]
        ]}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Results:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("6222ca4252925ad4c3faec08"), 
    "value" : [
        {
            "name" : "test1"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "test2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `{
  _id: ObjectId("6222ca4252925ad4c3faec08"),
  { 
    value: "test1",
    value: "test2"
  }
}` is not a valid json and also you cannot have the same key  `value` in object. Please make sure your expected result is a valid json.

Comment: @YuTing sorry about that.

Comment: So the keys should be of `value(N)` format ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj it doesn’t have to be. Just provided example of different keys

Comment: I've posted an answer. There's some difference in keys like it's value in document but you are running reduce on provider. So make sure you match those when trying out my answer (requires 'value' in document).

Comment: @Dharmaraj thank you for asking effective clarification questions to support this ask!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are just creating an array using [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/), Instead you can try using [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to create an array of format `[key, value]` and then use [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) to convert that to a map as shown below:

```
[
  {
    "$project": {
      "provider": {
        "$arrayToObject": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$value",
            "as": "v",
            "in": [
              {
                "$concat": [
                  "value",
                  {
                    "$toString": {
                      "$indexOfArray": [
                        "$value",
                        "$$v"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
              "$$v"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) is just to get key of format `value(N)`.

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/S5Q4Cw2E7x9)